# How do i get the frequency of the microphone in ChucK?

Tags: audio, adc, dac, chuck

I need to get the frequency that comes out of the microphone input, in order to play certain notes on a sequencer or any instrument depending on the microphone tone.
I use this code to output de microphone

```
adc => dac;  
while(true){
    0.1::second=>now;
    }
```

Is there any function that is used on adb to be able to do what I want?
Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to modify the Spectral Centroid UAna example.

```
/// sending the mic through the analysis instead of SinOsc
adc => FFT fft =^ Centroid cent => blackhole;

float trackedFrequency; 

512 => fft.size;
Windowing.hann(512) => fft.window;

second / samp => float srate;

while( true )
{
    cent.upchuck();

    // modifying the example to put the analysis in a variable
    cent.fval(0) * srate / 2 => trackedFrequency; 
    <<< trackedFrequency >>>; // use it set the frequency of something else

    fft.size()::samp => now; // advance time
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! 
I have noticed that the frequency is somewhat unstable, is there any way that if I play a note through the microphone the detected frequency is the same as the note?

Comment: I'd recommend you use [pitchFollower](https://github.com/heuermh/lick/blob/master/examples/pitchFollowerExample.ck), from the lick library instead. It's ridiculously accurate.